# How can I correctly get the price element from this api in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have tried to use an example of another api, which was working then tried to switch out the link and items in the struct. The only thing that I could comtemplate the issue being is the "Global Quote" in the api url. but I'm not sure.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Course: Hashable, Codable {
    let price: String
    let change: String
}

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case price = "05. price"
    case change = "09. change"
    
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var courses: [Course] = []
   
    func fetch() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=TSLA&apikey=<api-key>") else {
            return
        }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, _,
            error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            
            //Covert to JSON
            do {
                let courses = try JSONDecoder().decode([Course].self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.courses = courses
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
            
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                Text("help me")
                List {
                    ForEach(viewModel.courses, id: \.self) { course in
                        Text(course.price)
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Title")
                .onAppear {
                    viewModel.fetch()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting the price from the api to be pulled through correctly.

Comment: Add a sample json response.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - Same as the URL;

{
    "Global Quote": {
        "01. symbol": "TSLA",
        "02. open": "241.7700",
        "03. high": "243.7900",
        "04. low": "238.0200",
        "05. price": "242.6500",
        "06. volume": "99038642",
        "07. latest trading day": "2023-08-11",
        "08. previous close": "245.3400",
        "09. change": "-2.6900",
        "10. change percent": "-1.0964%"
    }
}

Comment: Your JSON doesn't match your models. See how the top of the JSON is a dictionary? Not an array? Paste your JSON into app.quicktype.io and look at the models it generates.

Comment: Add the sample to the question and/or follow the advice from jnpdx

Comment: Paste the JSOn into QuickType.io

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you do not get an array `[Course]` from the server, you get **one** `ServerResponse`
with **one** `Course` as shown in the example code.

So your code is missing the root element (`ServerResponse`) and should be decoding
that. You must also put the `Course` CodingKeys inside the `struct` as shown.

Assuming you have a valid apikey, the following example code works in fetching the desired data from the API.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var globalQuote: Course?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let gbq = globalQuote {
                Text(gbq.price)
                Text(gbq.change)
            }
        }
        .task {
            globalQuote = await getGlobalQuote(for: "TSLA")
        }
    }
    
    func getGlobalQuote(for theSymbol: String) async -> Course? {
        let apikey = "YOUR-APIKEY"
        if let url = URL(string: "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=\(theSymbol)&outputsize=full&apikey=\(apikey)") {
            do {
                let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
                let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(ServerResponse.self, from: data)
                return response.globalQuote
            }
            catch { print(error) }
        }
        return nil
    }
       
}

struct Course: Hashable, Codable {
    let price: String
    let change: String
    
    // ---- here inside the struct
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case price = "05. price"
        case change = "09. change"
        
    }
}

// --- here the root element
struct ServerResponse: Codable {
    let globalQuote: Course

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case globalQuote = "Global Quote"
    }
}
```